# subset doesn't recognize regex

Tags: regex, r, subset

I just cannot get this working. i want to subset all the rows containing "mail". I use this:

```
 Email <- subset(Total_Content, source == ".*mail.*")
```

I have rows like this ones:

```
"snt152.mail.live.com",
"mailing.serviciosmovistar.com",
"blu179.mail.live.com"
```

But when using: "View(Email)"

I just get a data.frame empty (just see the columns). I don't need to "scape" any metacharacter, because i need the "." to mean "anycharacter" and the "*" (0 or more times), right? Thanks.

Comment: Try `Email <- subset(Total_Content, grepl("^.*mail.*$", source))`

Comment: That's it. Thanks, @beginneR. May you explain why the need of using "grepl"? I've done other subsets without this. Of couse, the other ones did not use regex, were more simpliers.

Comment: See the answer below for why you need grepl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use subset with a logical regex funtion?

```
Email <- subset(Total_Content,  grepl(".*mail.*", source) )
```

The `subset` function does create a local environment for the evaluation of expressions that are used in either the 'subset' (row targets) or the 'select' (column targets) arguments.

Comment: this is what i was looking for. Nice and clean, thanks!

Comment: is there a way to apply a multiple condition with subset? For example, besides source = ".*mail.*", also Medium == "referral" (as a string)?

Comment: Of course! You can use the `&` ( or `|`) operator(s) with any other logical expression(s). The rule is that the fully evaluated expression must be of the same length as the number of rows in the dataframe.

Comment: may you indicate how? I have this: `Social_Media <- subset(Total_Content, grepl(".*faceb.*", source) │ grepl("social-media", Medium)`, but checking the data... it seems that only the first grepl is considered. For the bar i did: ALT  + 179 (│)

Comment: The dash is a special character in regex patterns you probably need to use `grepl("social\\-media", Medium)`

Comment: With that code i get this error:
**Error: unexpected input in "Social_Media3 <- subset(Total_Content, grepl(".*faceb.*", source) ¦"**
 Is some wrong with │(alt + 179)? thanks for your time man.

Comment: I think the problem is other, because usgin: `Social_Media2 <- subset(Total_Content, grepl(".*social\\-media.*", Medium))` or 

`Social_Media3 <- subset(Total_Content, grepl(".*social-media.*", Medium))`  gives the same result. There is something wrong with the or operator, i guess...

Comment: On both my Windows device and my Mac devices (with US keyboards) the "pipe" symbol (vectorized logical `OR`) is shift-backslash and alt-179 does not produce that symbol. You should look at `?"&"` to see the logical operators and include more detail on you locale and equipment.

Comment: Thanks, i did that ?"&"  and copied the "or" operator. I think, i've issues with characters enconding. I'll check it out, and post the info here. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

Well, no, it doesn't - it's not meant to. You're not passing it a regular expression to be evaluated against each row, you're just passing it a character string; it doesn't know that . and * are regex characters because it's not performing a regex search. It's returning all rows where source is the literal string .*mail.* - which in this case is 0 rows.

What you probably want to be doing (I'm assuming this is a data.frame, here) is:

```
Email <- Total_Content[grepl(x = Total_Content$source, pattern = ".*mail.*"),]
```

grepl produces a set of boolean values of whether each entry in Total_Content$source matched the pattern. Total_Content[boolean_vector,] limits to those rows of Total_Content where the equivalent boolean is TRUE.

Comment: thanks, @Oliver Keyes. So, subset does not take regex, but grepl does. Correct me, if im wrong. 

May you tell me how to use grepl and apply it for two conditions: e.g. source == ".*mail.*" $ Medium = "referral".

Yes, you were correct, this was a data frame.

Comment: Is "referral" a regex or just a string? If it's a string, Total_Content[grepl(x = Total_Content$source, pattern = ".*mail.*") & Total_Content$Medium == "referral",]. If it's a pattern, you'll need two grepl statements, in the form Total_Content[grepl1() & grepl2(),]